# Hardcoded Mapping to the Destination

Tags: ssis, salesforce, cozyroc

I am trying to create a SSIS package for the interface between SQL Server and the Salesforce. I have created the connection between the systems and using a third party COZYROC Connector for SF connection and the data flow looks like below

[image]

I am not able to do any hardcoded mapping to the fields in Salesforce

While mapping it just shows the available input columns there is no way where I can set the hardcoded values for some fileds while doing an upsert. How can this be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) is what you are after.

Dragged that from the tool box

[image]

Place it between you source and destination. Double click on it and you can add columns and default values.  Leave the "Derived Column" option in the table as "add as new column"

[image]

Then those become available for mapping in the destination component.

[image]